# Find all elements of order $4$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_6.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find all elements of order $4$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Technically, I know how to find the order of an element in a group. In this case, let's say I have the element $(1,2,3)$, I'll look for the order of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Then I'll take the least common multiple of these orders and that should be it. Is that right?

Now, don't know how to go the other way around. I though about finding elements of order $4$ in each group ($\mathbb{Z}_8 $,$\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ because $lcm(4,4,4)=4$. But still, that wouldn't be all of them.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: I just want to put it out there that this is not a homework question. I'm just trying to study and understand the concepts.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z/5$ all elements (except $e$) have order $5$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you! I'm new here and didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were saying, we have that the order of an element $(g,h)$ in a direct product $G \times H$ is given by the least common multiple of the orders of $g$ and $h$. Now when do we have $4$ as the lcm of the orders?

As $4 =2^2$ is a prime power, we will get that exactly when at least one of the orders is $4$ and the orders of the other two elements are smaller powers of $2$. Which possible combinations can arise for your groups? Can you continue?

Comment: Yes! My answer would be that the possible elements are: (2,0,0) (2,0,3) (6,0,0) (6,0,3). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You found them.